# Sharing Documents links with the world

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I clicked on the 'Share' link and was presented with a small popup window containing the URL.

[image]

Isn't the 'soup du jour' behaviour currently using a back end routine to copy that to my clipboard? Right-click & Copy isn't a big deal but I wonder why that was left out. If I click on a link to share there is a very small possibility that I will want to stop the process at that point.

[image]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606221/copy-a-text-when-a-link-or-button-is-clicked) if it is any help.

On a related subject, is there a twitter hashtag I should be using if I want to post links to quality documentation?

Comment: The share function on SO Posts behaves the same. I recall UX specialists find consistency important.

Comment: Them paint skills though...

Comment: Web applications have very limited access to the clipboard.  Which is a good thing.  A very good thing.  There are hacky ways to do it, some more hacky than others.  They all pretty much suck for developers to implement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Messing with my clipboard is massively unfriendly, IMHO. I believe this is unreliable from a technical standpoint too (apparently certain browser makers also feel that messing with my clipboard without my permission is unfriendly).

Comment: This also allows people to drag and drop the link instead. I will sometimes do that if my clipboard is full of something else.

Comment: Oh-key-doh-key. So should I infer that there is now a down-turn in copying a url to the clipboard when clicking a 'share this' link?

Comment: Just implemented this recently in muh product the same way.  Clipboard hacks all stink to high heaven.  This method for presenting a link for the user to copy is pretty common.  Slack's method is really slick, tho.  There's a question about it on SO, but I can't find it right now :(